# remove option from all select boxes of the same class except the one clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a booking form for a hotel, where customers can elect who the share a room with.
each row represents one guest name and the have a drop down menu () with the id numbers of all the other guest as options.

when a guest in row one decides to share a room with guest id=3, I want row ones drop down box to show a 3, row 3 to show a one and all the other rows to have 1 and 3 options removed from their select boxes.

I have got the below code, but the .not(this), is not working, any pointers as to why would be warmly appreciated.

here is the form

```
<?php
    for($a=0;$a<15;$a++)
    {
        echo "
<tr id=".($a+1)."><td>".($a+1)."</td>
    <td><select name='title[]'>
        <option value='Ms'>Ms</option>
        <option value='Mrs'>Mrs</option>
        <option value='Mr'>Mr</option>
        <option value='Dr'>Dr</option>
        </select></td> 
    <td><input type='text' name='firstname[]' size='10'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lastname[]' size='10' ></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email[]'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='passport_no[]'></td>
    <td><input type='date' name='dob[]' size='10'></td>
    <td><select name='room_pref[]' class='room_pref'>
        <option value='TWIN'>twin</option>
        <option value='DOUBLE'>double</option>
        <option value='SINGLE'>single</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><select name='share_w[]' class='share'>";
   for($b=1;$b<16;$b++)
   {
       echo "<option value=".$b.">".$b."</option>";
   }     

  echo "<option value ='ALONE'>Alone</option>
 </select></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='diet[]'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='allergies[]'></td>
 </tr>";
```

?>

and here is my jquery

```
$('.share').change(function(){
    var shareW=$(this).val();
    $(".share option[value="+shareW+"]").not(this).remove();
}):
```

Comment: What's your actual representative (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML? Your PHP executes server-side, what does it send to the browser for JavaScript to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` here means `select` not `option`, you need to apply not on the `.share` collection and not on `option`.

Try

```
 $(".share").not(this).children("option[value="+ this.value +"]").remove();
```

You could also avoid creating `.share` collection over and again in the click handler.

```
var $share = $('.share');
$share.change(function(){
    $share.not(this).children("option[value="+ this.value +"]").remove();
});
```

Comment: thanks for not only the answer but correcting my understanding

Comment: @MarkGilchrist Its is just that you don't want to create the object `$('.share')` collection over and again. If you are not adding any other `.share` dynamically this will hold the collection.